# Excluding points from polygon QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.18

I have population points for Germany and a polygon of an urban area. I've joined population data with the polygon to obtain the population of that urban area. 
Now my aim is to obtain a layer with points that fall outside the polygon. Is there a way to do so?
[image]

Comment: Use the 'Select by polygon' tool with the concerned layers as input, then use the 'Invert selection' tool. When the correct points are selected, right-click the layer, go to the export section and choose 'Save selected features as...'

Comment: @GabrielC. thanks for your input, however I can't find the "select polygon" tool anywhere, I'm using QGIS 2.18.25

Comment: Given the answer to your other question, once you have features selected, you can simply use the attribute table to 'invert the selection', then export those features to a new shapefile.

Comment: @csk provided the answer that works with 2.18. The 'Select features by Polygon' tool doesn't work with polygon layers until QGIS 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the `select by location` tool in the Processing Toolbox. Use the `select by location` tool with the following settings:

- *Select features from* **population point layer**
- *Where the features (geometry predicate)* **disjoint**
- *By comparing to the features from* **urban area polygon layer**

Now you have selected all the points that fall outside the urban area. Export the selection as a new layer (Right click on point layer in layer panel > Export > Save Selected Features as...).